# Lines deletions has been done but there is no commit to blame

Tags: git, git-log, git-status

Some lines has been deleted from a file, and I'd like to know when and how it happened.

But: no faulty commit to be found. Really strange.

Here is `git log`, that shows (as last changes) the commit when the lines were added:

```sh
$ git log --follow -p -- src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php 
commit 80dc439aba2bf38ed7e95888dd21c1ba0f8960ce
Author: Benoit <benoit.guchet@gmail.Com>
Date:   Tue Jul 16 18:31:38 2019 +0200

    Opti Doctrine #814

diff --git a/src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php b/src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php
index 7dfc2f963..a3e916690 100644
--- a/src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php
+++ b/src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php
@@ -10,12 +10,15 @@ namespace QsGeneralBundle\Repository;
  */
 class EmployeeRepository extends BaseRepository
 {
-       public function findAllQb() {
-               $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
+    public function findAllQb() {
+        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
             ->innerJoin('e.Account', 'a')
-                       ->orderBy('a.firstname', 'ASC')
-                       ->addOrderBy('a.lastname', 'ASC')
-            ->andWhere('a.isEnabled = TRUE');
+            ->leftJoin('a.SpecificRole', 'r')
+            ->leftJoin('a.Contractor', 'c')
+            ->orderBy('a.firstname', 'ASC')
+            ->addOrderBy('a.lastname', 'ASC')
+            ->andWhere('a.isEnabled = TRUE')
+            ->select('e, a, r, c');

                return $qb;
        }
```

Now here is the current content of the file:

```php
<?php

namespace QsGeneralBundle\Repository;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Benoît Guchet
 * Date: 16/11/2016
 * Time: 13:26
 */
class EmployeeRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    public function findAllQb() {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->innerJoin('e.Account', 'a')
            ->orderBy('a.firstname', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('a.lastname', 'ASC')
            ->andWhere('a.isEnabled = TRUE');

        return $qb;
    }
}
```

Which has no local changes as shown by `git status`:

```sh
$ git status src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php 
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Any piece of mind about this mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php` has never been renamed (or not in the range of commits that will be displayed), you can omit the `--follow` and add, instead, `--full-history` and `-m`.

There are two problems here:

- First, the change you are looking for probably occurred during a merge.  Without `-m` (or some other arguments that also aren't the default), `git log` ignores *all* changes committed during a merge.
- Second, when you specify a file name such as `src/QsGeneralBundle/Repository/EmployeeRepository.php` (with or without `--follow`), Git turns on *History Simplification*.  When history simplification is on, Git simply *doesn't bother to look* at some commits.  In particular it won't follow the leg of a merge that (incorectly—but see footnote) doesn't *take* a change that you think the merge *should* take.

Hence by forcing the history simplification to keep all commits (`--full-history`) and forcing `git log` to show merge commits as *two* `git diff`s, you should be able to find where the commit you want was (incorrectly) dropped.

---

Footnote: Git assumes that the result of each merge is the *correct* result.  That is, suppose a merge commit has, as its right-side incoming-branch changes, a bug fix, and as its left-side changes, no changes at all.  Suppose further that whoever made the merge dropped the bug fix:

```
o another commit (has bug)
|
* merge commit (has bug, person who merged dropped the fix)
|\
o | main line work (has bug)
| |
| o fix for bug
|/
o main line work (has bug)
```

Git *assumes* that the right-side changes—the bug fix—were instead the *introduction* of a bug, which the person who made the merge was smart and omitted, keeping the *left*-side version that (according to the person doing the merge, and hence now according to Git too) was "correct".  In fact, that merge commit was *wrong* ... but when Git does History Simplification, Git assumes that it was right.  So Git follows only the left side of the commit graph at this point.  You never see the bug fix!

The only way to see the commit with the fix is to avoid or disable History Simplification (leave out the file name, or add `--full-history`).  But since by default, `git log -p` won't diff the merge commit against the bug-fix commit, even that's not sufficient.

---

Additional footnote: note that file names, in Git, are the *entire path*.  If a file was named `a/b/c.ext` and is now named `a/d/c.ext`, this one file has two different names.  Git does not store directories / folders, which is [why you cannot store an empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452).  (Side note to the footnote: there *is* an empty tree object in every repository, but using it leads to problems later as Git keeps trying to convert this into a submodule—see the linked question for details.)

The way Git deals with your computer's insistence on using directories / folders—which is what allows your OS to provide *empty* ones—is to coddle your OS.  Git just extracts the *files* for a commit, and if your OS demands that a file whose Git-name is `a/b/c.ext` be created as file `c.ext` in folder `b` in folder `a`, well, then, Git creates folder `a` and then folder `a/b` so as to create a file whose name is `a/b/c.ext`.  If there are *no* files whose name starts with `a/b`, Git just doesn't *create* `a/b` in the first place.

In any case, the fundamental problem with `--follow` is that its implementation is a cheesy hack.  Suppose that history—i.e., the backwards-looking chain of commits in the repository—looks something like this, with later commits towards the right:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N   <-- branch
         /
...--K--L
```

where each letter stands in for an actual commit hash.  In commit `N` you have a file named `a/d/c.ext`; in commit `I`, that same file has name `a/b/c.ext`.  The *way* that `git log --follow a/d/c.ext` handles this is to look at each commit-pair, one step at a time:

- First, Git looks at the `M-N` pair.

  Is the file named `a/b/c.ext` in `M`, and `a/d/c.ext` in `N`?  If so, then as soon as Git works on the `J-M` and `L-M` pairs, Git will *stop* looking for `a/d/c.ext` and start, instead, looking for `a/b/c.ext` (the old name, not the current nam).

  If not—if it's still `a/d/c.ext` in `M`—then when Git compares `J` and `M`, or compares `L` and `M`, it will look for `a/d/c.ext` (the current name, not the old name).
- Next, Git looks at either the `J-M` or `L-M` pair—or, if doing History Simplification and not forced *not* to, picks one of the pair to look at and doesn't really look at the other pair, nor follow that leg of the branch.

  If the file is renamed in one of these pairs, but not the other, Git really can't handle this.  Without `--full-history` Git will pick one leg to follow and, to some extent, pretend there isn't a merge and the rename detection can work (although I'm not sure it does, given the other oddities that `git log` displays around merges).  If the file isn't renamed in *either* pair, though, we're still good: the file still has its new name, so if we force `--full-history`, so that Git must now traverse both legs of the merge, Git will do that.  Let's say it now does the `I-J` part:
- Now Git compares commits `I` and `J`.  Was the file renamed here?  **Let's say it *was* renamed here.  In effect, Git says to itself: *Aha, let's stop looking for `a/d/c.ext`; from now on, let's look for `a/b/c.ext`.***  When Git compares commit `I` with whatever comes before commit `I`, that works.
- But, having followed that leg of the merge for a while, Git now—under `--full-history` anyway—goes back and compares commits `K` and `L`, from the *other* leg of the merge.  Git goes to check on file `a/b/c.ext`, as that's the path it now believes the file has.  **But the file still has the `a/d/c.ext` name in *this* leg of the merge.**  The result is that `git log --follow` is looking for *the wrong file!*

To make this all work, `git log --follow` would need to be *way* more clever than it really is.  All `--follow` does is change *the one file name* it is looking for, and it does not remember that it did so in some particular *part* of the commit graph.  Git needs to somehow tie the name change to the graph traversal, and "undo" the change whenever it goes back "up" the graph (but Git doesn't really go up: it really just puts commits into a priority queue, which means there is no place to put this name-change information).

If all the name changes happen in the "right" places, `--follow` and `--full-history` *can* mix well.  For instance, if the name-change to `a/d/c.ext` from the old name `a/b/c.ext` happens in the `M-N` pair, so that *all* the older commits have the old name—then `--follow` and `--full-history` have no problem following both legs of the merge: the file has only the one name from `M` on back in history and the `--follow` changes the one name at the right time.  It's when the name-change happens in *parallel* histories, in multiple different merge legs, that this screws up.

Comment: Strangely enough, it was never renamed (only a parent subdirectory years ago), but `git log` doesn't even include that last changes commit while `git log --follow` does...

Comment: Anyway thanks, adding `--full-history -m` indeed shows me that a merge is to blame. Git did it automatically :/ can I trust git auto merges? Or must I always recheck everything?

Comment: It did the same for a lot of files

Comment: Git doesn't store directories, Git only stores files. If the file's name was `a/b/c` once and is now `a/d/c`, the file has been renamed: the file's name is the full string. That's not a directory, it's just part of the file name!

Comment: As for what happened in the merge, well, you can *repeat* the merge to see if it really was Git that did this; and/or you can look at the two diffs from the three commits, to see what Git saw that might make Git do this. My bet is that Git declared a conflict during merge and someone used either `-X` or `-s` to "fix" the conflict by ignoring one side of the merge (or did the equivalent in a merge tool).